# Write Test case in c# at a time 50 people call same process in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, testcase

i want to create test case which allow to hit 50 times at a time get their results individually.

want to know what happen if 50 people come at a time

Comment: Do you want to write an automated test or do you want to write a test case? If you want to write a test case, maybe try [Software Quality Assurance Stack Exchange](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Look at the load testing tools in Visual Studio.

Comment: @JohnWu i want to write test case but it should not in foreach

Comment: I think you want to write an automated test or a test *script*, which is a program that executes a test. A test *case* is written in English (or the language of your department) and describes preconditions, steps, and expected outcome, so a QA engineer can execute it with precision and repeatability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention why you don't want to use `foreach`, but here is a way to do it with LINQ, assuming you have a single-user test that can be invoked with a function named `ExecuteTestForAUser()` (yours may differ):

```
const numberOfTests = 50;
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, numberOfTests)
    .Select
    ( 
        i => Task.Run( () => ExecuteTestForAUser() ) 
    )
    .ToArray();
Task.WaitAll( tasks );
```

This code produces a list of 50 integers using `Enumerable.Range`. It then converts the list into a list of 50 tasks using `Select`. `Task.Run()` will put each task on the thread pool. Then `Task.WaitAll()` will block execution until they have all completed.

You will need to make sure `ExecuteTestForAUser()` is thread-safe.

Comment: foreach will run test one by one. i want to make test same time @john Wu

Comment: I don't understand your comment. My example does not contain `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

I you looking to create a load test then you can use [visual studio enterprise 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/load-test/run-performance-tests-app-before-release?view=vsts) to create and run load test.

Also you can use a free tool like [JMeter](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-jmeter-to-perform-load-testing-on-a-web-server) not that fancy but it gets the job done.

Comment: dear its a method which i wanna test for 50 user at a time